# PyCharm Mac Biopython installation

Tags: macos, pycharm, biopython

I'm a newbie in PyCharm, and using it as general IDE for python.

My problem here is that when I run my code in PyCharm, it doesn't see BioPython. It says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[path-to-code]", line 9, in <module>
from Bio import SeqIO
ImportError: No module named Bio
```

So I went to 'Preferences->Project:code->Project structure' and added entire site-packages as content root. But then, PyCharm won't run at all and gives this error:

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
```

Anyone faced similar problem before?

Note: Console python can recognize when I import Bio, and works just fine.

Comment: The problem is solved. PyCharm and Console were pointing to different interpretators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of altering your project structure, in the preferences go to `Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter`. Click the `+` and search for `biopython`.

[image]

Comment: That's what I did at first place, actually. But I don't see the biopython in the list.

Comment: Ah, I think I got the problem. I'm on a non-admin user, and have installed PyCharm on my local folder, not in    Applications folder. Probably PyCharm is not able to see biopython because it doesn't have access.

Comment: The problem still hangs. Sublime Text can see and access the biopython, but not PyCharm.

Comment: Did you choose an interpreter that has biopython installed? I think pycharm will default to the mac system python. Which probably is not where you installed biopython.

Comment: Yes, you were right. Though the `sys.version` was showing same information, it was pointing to different interpretator.

Comment: @SanjarbekHudaiberdiev how did you change which interpreter sys.version was pointing? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Workhorse in the "Project interpreter" it should show the available python interpreters. From that list, you can try to choose different interpreters and try to run your code. If your interpreter is not in the list, you can show it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks!! I ended up closing and re-opening Pycharm, and that seemed to work!